# Filter By Specific words in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe which has following data

```
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |text                                                                                                                                               |
    +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    |Know what you don't do at 1:30 when you can't sleep? Music shopping. Now I want to dance. #shutUpAndDANCE                                          |
    |Serasi ade haha @AdeRais "@SMTOWNGLOBAL: #SHINee ONEW(@skehehdanfdldi) and #AMBER(@llama_ajol) at KBS 'Music Bank'."        |
    |Happy Birhday Ps.Jeffrey Rachmat #JR50 #flipagram  ? Music: This I Believe (The Creed) - Hillsong…                          |
```

The dataframe is of one column 'text' and has words containing # in them. e.g.
'#shutUpAndDANCE'

I am trying to read each word and filter out so that I am left with a list of words only with hash

Code:

```
#Gets only those rows containing
hashtagList = sqlContext.sql("SELECT text FROM tweetstable WHERE text LIKE '%#%'")
print hashtagList.show(100, truncate=False)

#Process Rows to get the words
hashtagList = hashtagList.map(lambda p: p.text).map(lambda x: x.split(" ")).collect() 
print hashtagList
```

The output is :

```
[[u'Know', u'what', u'you', u"don't", u'do', u'at', u'1:30', u'when', u'you', u"can't", u'sleep?', u'Music', u'shopping.', u'Now', u'I', u'want', u'to', u'dance.', u'#shutUpAndDANCE'], [...]]
```

Is there a way that I can filter out everything and keep only the #words during my map stage.

```
hashtagList = hashtagList.map(lambda p: p.text).map(lambda x: x.split(" "))<ADD SOMETHING HERE TO FETCH ONLY #>.collect()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from __future__ import print_function

str = "Know what you don't do at 1:30 when you can't sleep? Music shopping. Now I want to dance. #shutUpAndDANCE Serasi ade haha @AdeRais @SMTOWNGLOBAL: #SHINee ONEW(@skehehdanfdldi) and #AMBER(@llama_ajol) at KBS 'Music Bank'.Happy Birhday Ps.Jeffrey Rachmat #JR50 #flipagram? Music: This I Believe (The Creed) - Hillsong"
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(str)]);
words = df.rdd.flatMap(list).flatMap(lambda line: line.split()).filter(lambda word: word.startswith("#"));
words.foreach(print)
```

Comment: But this is in scala right? what will be the python equivalent, use lambda?

Comment: hashtagList.rdd.map(lambda p: p.text.encode("ascii", "ignore")).flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")).filter(lambda word: word.startsWith("#")).collect() , I get error on this line

Comment: Edited and added python version

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```py
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import split, explode, col
>>>
>>> df.select(explode(split("text", "\\s+")).alias("word")) \
...     .where(col("word").startswith("#"))
```